# Unir dos objetos en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de fusionar dos objetos:

```
obj1 = [
  {date: '2020-04-01', count: 0},
  {date: '2020-04-02', count: 0},
  {date: '2020-04-03', count: 0},
  {date: '2020-04-04', count: 0},
]

obj2 = [
  {date: '2020-04-02', count: 20},
  {date: '2020-04-04', count: 2},
]
```

Estoy uniendo los dos objetos de la siguiente manera:

```
let newObj = [...obj1, ...obj2]
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
[{date: "2020-04-01", count: 0},
{date: "2020-04-02", count: 0},
{date: "2020-04-03", count: 0},
{date: "2020-04-04", count: 0},
{date: "2020-04-02", count: 20},
{date: "2020-04-04", count: 2}]
```

Lo que intento obtener es eliminar los objetos con fechas repetidas que su valor sea 0 si es duplicado.

Objeto esperado:

```
[{date: "2020-04-01", count: 0},
 {date: "2020-04-02", count: 20},
 {date: "2020-04-03", count: 0},
 {date: "2020-04-04", count: 2}]
```

Eliminando objetos repetidos obtengo lo siguiente:

```
const uniqueObjects = [...new Map(newObj.map(item => [item.date, item])).values()]

[{date: "2020-04-01", count: 0},
 {date: "2020-04-02", count: 20},
 {date: "2020-04-03", count: 0},
 {date: "2020-04-04", count: 2}]
```

Pero como verifico que se eliminen correctamente los objetos con la condición mencionada (eliminar los objetos con fechas repetidas que su valor sea 0 si es duplicado.)

Comment: Necesitas que se sumen los count en caso de que por ejemplo para el día 4 exista uno con 0 otro con 3 y otro con 2. ¿Ósea que resulte 5 o que los separe?

Comment: Exacto, pero solo habrán como máximo dos valores repetidos.

Comment: Lo esperado y lo que estás obteniendo me parece que están iguales, ¿podrías dar más detalles de qué comportamiento esperas?